# Most appropriate Lifetime Manager for Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

Currently I'm using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.HierarchicalLifetimeManager as the lifetime manager for my controllers because it calls dispose on the objects it contains. However, it seems that I'm running into cross-threading issues now (multiple request variables are getting mixed up). Reading further into the lifetime manager, it implements a Singleton pattern, which I believe is my problem.

I'm using Unity 2.1. Can any recommend the most appropriate lifetime manager to use with ASP.net MVC controllers, that will call dispose on each of its contained objects at the end of each request?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think any [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) that don't implement as a singleton should work. You'll need to pick the best for your needs. `PerThreadLifetimeManager` sounds pretty good, although it doesn't call `Dispose`. However, it will be garbage collected when the thread dies.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if IIS will guarantee a unique thread per request? If so, using PreThreadLifetimeManager would effectively be a PerRequestLifetimeManager, correct?

Comment: Thanks. I'll find a way around the Dispose issue.

Comment: My understanding is that IIS requests are **not** guaranteed to be tied to a thread for the duration of the call as per http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html.

Comment: IIS *may* switch threads, but only at a very specific point in the request cycle, namely between `BeginRequest` and `Page_Load`. As we're talking about lifetime management for a controller, I don't think it ends up having any bearing on anything here.